# Parse for Unity crash in Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-8, parse-platform, crash, windows-store

I've finished a Unity game which i want to publish in Google Play, Windows Phone Store and Windows 8 Store. I'm using the very last version of Parse for Unity SDK (1.4.1) and also the last version of Unity Editor (4.6.4p4), including last patches.

The Parse implementation i made in my game works perfectly on:
- Unity Editor (all platforms)
- Android (deploying apk on two devices)
- Android (Publishing the game as alpha, installing it in +8 devices)
- Windows Phone 8 (All Windows Phone Emulators - 8.0 and 8.1 - x86)
- Windows Phone 8 (debugging on device with both Visual Studio 2012 for Windows Phone and Visual Studio 2013 Community - ARM)

It does'nt work on:
- Windows Phone 8 (deploying as a Beta)
- Windows Phone 8 (deploying as Hidden release)

The game crashes every time i try to use any function of the Parse SDK, throws no exception, the Windows Phone 8 Store gives me no info about any crashes... seems like an assembly load issue...

I've no idea what is happening, this issue is stoping me to publishing my game, think i'm going crazy...

So, i've made a simple dummy app to test my parse implementation, and... it has the same issue... it's very simple: Only a gameobject which has the "Parse Initialize Behaviour" attached (with both AppId and .NET keys setted) and a very simple script:

```
    using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Xml;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System;
using System.Linq;
using Parse;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


// Demo application script
public class AppScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static string userName = "Caldofran";
    public static string userPass = "Password5";
    public static string userEmail = "caldofran@email.com";
    public static string errAsincrono = "";
    public static string log = "";

    public static bool bLogin = false;
    public static bool bSignUp = false;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

        //Application.runInBackground = true;

    }


    GUIStyle ts = new GUIStyle();

void OnGUI()
    {
            if (GUI.Button(new Rect(10, 100, 100, 30), "Sign Up"))
                SignUp(userName,userPass, userEmail);

            if (GUI.Button(new Rect(10, 150, 100, 30), "Login"))
                Login(userName, userPass);


                if (GUI.Button(new Rect(10, 200, 100, 30), "Logout"))
                    Logout();

        if (GUI.Button(new Rect(10, 300, 100, 30), "Clear Texts"))
        {
            errAsincrono = "";
            log = "";
        }


            int left = Screen.width - 110;

            string usrParse = "";

            if (AppScript.IsLoggedInParse())
                usrParse = ParseUser.CurrentUser.Username;

            ts.normal.textColor = Color.red;

            GUI.BeginGroup(new Rect(300, 5, 600, 500));
            GUI.Box(new Rect(0, 0, 400, 300), "");
            //GUILayout.Label("P: " + mensajeGUI);
        GUILayout.Label("User Config: " + userName, ts);
        GUILayout.Label("Pass config: " + userPass, ts);
        GUILayout.Label("email config: " + userEmail, ts);
        GUILayout.Label("Logged in parse: " + AppScript.IsLoggedInParse().ToString(), ts);
            GUILayout.Label("Parse logged user: " + usrParse, ts);
        GUILayout.Label("Last msg: " + errAsincrono, ts);
        GUILayout.Label("Last Log: " + log, ts);

            GUI.EndGroup();
    }   

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {


        if (bLogin)
        {
            bLogin = false;
            log += " Login Update text";
        }

        if (bSignUp)
        {
            bSignUp = false;
            log += " SignUp Update text";
        }


    }



    #region Parse

    public static bool IsLoggedInParse()
    {
        bool retorno = false;
        if ((ParseUser.CurrentUser != null) && (ParseUser.CurrentUser.IsAuthenticated))
            retorno = true;

        return retorno;
    }

    public static void SignUp(string userName, string passWord, string email)
    {
        var user = new ParseUser()
        {
            Username = userName,
            Password = passWord
        };
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(email))
            user.Email = "";
        else
            user.Email = email;

        try
        {
            Task signUpTask = user.SignUpAsync().ContinueWith(t=>
            {
                if (t.IsFaulted || t.IsCanceled)
                {
                    // The login failed. Check the error to see why.
                    foreach(var e in t.Exception.InnerExceptions) {
                        ParseException parseException = (ParseException) e;
                        log += parseException.Message + ": CODE: " +  parseException.Code.ToString();
                    }
                    errAsincrono = t.Exception.Message;
                }
                else
                {
                    // Signup was successful.
                    log = "Welcome " + userName;
                    bSignUp = true;
                }
            });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            errAsincrono =  "Error: " + ex.Message;
        }
    }

    public static void Login(string user, string pass)
    {
        try
        {
            ParseUser.LogInAsync(user, pass).ContinueWith(t =>
             {
                 if (t.IsFaulted || t.IsCanceled)
                 {
                     // The login failed. Check the error to see why.
                    foreach(var e in t.Exception.InnerExceptions) {
                        ParseException parseException = (ParseException) e;
                        log += parseException.Message + ": CODE: " +  parseException.Code.ToString();
                    }
                    errAsincrono = t.Exception.Message;
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     // Login was successful.
                    log = "Welcome back " + userName;
                    AppScript.bLogin = true;
                 }
             });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            errAsincrono =  "Error: " + ex.Message;
        }
    }

    public static void ResetPassword(string email)
    {
        if (IsLoggedInParse())
        {
            Task requestPasswordTask = ParseUser.RequestPasswordResetAsync(email);
            log = "Pass reset ok";
        }
    }

    public static void Logout()
    {

        if (IsLoggedInParse())
        {
            ParseUser.LogOutAsync();
            log = "Logged out ";
        }
    }

    #endregion


}
```

Can anybody try it? What i'm doing wrong? Why this code works nearly always but not in Windows Phone (published on the store)?

I've read about Unity bug, which affects only to iOS: http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/unity-5-parse-ios-nsurlerrordomain-error-1012.308569/
This bug (consuming WWW trough SSL) affects Windows Phone apps?

Comment: Any ideas? Can anyone test this problem?

Comment: I don't know anything about Parse or Unity, but one common cause of apps crashing in the Store is if you try and write / modify files in your installation directory. This is allowed during debugging, but not when deployed from the Store.

Comment: I really have no idea of what is happening, i have no logs, no exceptions... nothing. I've report a bug to the Parse team, and it seems it has been accepted as a bug...

Answer (score 0):

In my case, using Parse SDK 1.6.1 for Windows.
To set Password property throws ArgumentException.
The cause was in Master build configuration and .NET Native tool chain.

Solution 1:
Uncheck "Compile with .NET Native tool chain" in Project's Build settings.

Solution 2:
Create subclass of ParseUser and define "new" properties Username and Password.